# ruby's command line -F option, how is it used?

Tags: ruby

I want to use the ruby's -F option to define a field separator (tab, for instance). I have tried various expressions like -F:\t and -F='\t' etc. but can't seem to get the correct syntax. Does anyone know the correct syntax? Can you please show me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a ruby file (call it test.rb) with the following line. A tab appears after the three numbers, and everything else is spaces or letters:

```
puts "123       456     789     some words split by spaces".split
```

When you run with default args:

```
ruby test.rb
```

You get the following output:

```
123

456

789

some

words

split

by

spaces
```

If you want the input separator to be only \t, then you should set the -F option surrounded by "". For example:

```
ruby -F"\t" test.rb
```

produces the following output:

```
123

456

789

some words split by spaces
```

The key is to put the -F option values in double quotes.